# Kotlin Selenium Chromedriver doesn't exist

Tags: linux, selenium, web-scraping, kotlin

I'm trying to make a webscraping app with Kotlin. Since the websites I'll be scraping are JS generated I've been trying to make Selenium work but I've been stumped with this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /home/nexus/Downloads/chromedriver
```

I've already use 'chmod 777' with the driver and tried it also with the AUR verison.

Here's the code from my scraping function

```
package com.example.nexus.scraper

import android.os.AsyncTask
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

class Scrape(): AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/nexus/Downloads/chromedriver")
        var driver: WebDriver = ChromeDriver()
        driver.get("www.google.com")
        return null
    }
}
```

And here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nexus.scraper"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"    
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.41.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was caused by using Selenium and not Selendrium

Answer (score 2):

i would highly recommend to use [webdriver manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) instead of setting up the browser binaries yourself.

to instatiate a new chrome driver i would place a function like this in my code:

```
fun chrome(): WebDriver {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup()
    return ChromeDriver(chromeOptions())
}
```

now you can just use this function that will be returning your chrome driver like this:

```
val driver = chrome()
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

webdriver manager will take care about setting up the driver binaries automatically depending on your current operating system.
For a more complex example that gives the possibility to dynamically switch between different browser or driver settings and a complete selenium setup please have a look [here](https://github.com/christian-draeger/basic-selenium-project/blob/01c8b74d66b689b6df7841f0a05dee989442c76d/src/test/java/config/driver/DriverFactory.kt)

because you want to scrape a website i guess the chrome headless mode should be your choice because it's more efficient in terms of browser startup times etc.

In general i would recommend to use **[skrape{it}](https://docs.skrape.it/docs/)** instead of selenium to do the job (as long as you don't have to click somewhere). it's a library written in kotlin that has been specifically design to scrape websites and supports scraping of javascript rendered websites. For instance you could do something like this and you are done (no selenium overhead needed):

```
val githubName = skrape {
    url = "https://github.com/skrapeit"
    mode = Mode.DOM
    extract {
        element(".h-card .p-nickname").text()
    }
}
```

this will also work with more complex data, e.g:

```
data class MyScrapedData(
    val userName: String, 
    val repositoryNames: List<String>
)

fun main() {
    val githubUserData = skrape {
        url = "https://github.com/skrapeit"
        mode = Mode.DOM

        extract {
            MyScrapedData(
                userName = element(".h-card .p-nickname").text(),
                repositoryNames = elements("span.repo").map { it.text() }
            )
        }
    }
    println("${githubUserData.userName}'s repos are ${githubUserData.repositoryNames}")
}
```

for a full example on how to scrape a javascript rendered website with skrape{it} please have a look at their corresponding [docs section](https://docs.skrape.it/docs/dsl/extract-client-side-rendered-data)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the chromedriver directory in gradle.build:

```
 '--webdriver.chrome.driver=/home/nexus/Downloads/chromedriver'
```

Comment: Where in the gradle.build? Thanks

Comment: I don't know exactly. I guess as an separate section under dependencies. So is the configuration in my gradle.build. I use gradle/chromedriver/java/kotlin. I converted some code to kotlin and the gradle.build don't differs in this case.

Comment: I get a "Could not find method bootRun() for arguments [build_2xxhsdyepkutmlh7n527jg8dp$_run_closure3@6ecb0f76] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project." error

Comment: The question is how to add the args to gradle.build for an android-app. My example was from a springboot-app. This question does not belong to kotlin only, it's the same for java. It's about gradle and chromedriver.